# Is $\forall x\exists x(x < x)$ a sentence?

Tags: logic, definition, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Going through my notes on predicate logic, I read the following inductive definitions:

**Definition:** An *atomic term* is either a variable or a constant. If $f$ is an $n$-place function symbol and $t_1, . . . , t_n$ are *terms*, then $f(t_1, . . . , t_n)$ is also a *term*.

**Definition:** An *atomic formula* is a string of the form $P(t_1, . . . , t_n)$ for the $n$-place predicate $P$ (which may be the equal sign) and the terms $t_1, . . . , t_n$. If $F$ and $G$ are *formulas*, so are
$$\neg F,(F ∧ G),(F ∨ G), ∃xF, ∀xF.$$

**Definition:** An occurrence of a variable $x$ in a formula $F$ is *bound* iff it is part of a subformula beginning with $∃x . . .$ or $∀x . . .$, in which the quantifier in question is said to *bind* the variable, and otherwise the occurrence is said to be *free*. A formula is a *sentence* iff no occurrence of any variable in it is free.

It seems to me that these definitions allow for formulas such as
$$\forall x\exists x (x < x)$$
to be a sentence. If so, is that not problematic? Once semantics are introduced, the interpretation gives a truth value to every sentence, but the above formula does not seem to be of the kind deserving of a truth value.

Comment: Yes it is. Usually, the formal specifications of syntax allow for "null quantification": a formula like $\forall x \varphi$ where $x$ does not occur free in $\varphi$ is simply equivalent to $\varphi$.

Comment: Thus, in your specific example, with the usual interpretation of $\lt$, the formula $\exists x (x < x)$ is simly false.

Comment: Just to really spell out Bram28's nice answer in simple terms: the expression is evaluated from the inside out (or from right to left). So the $x$'s in $x<x$ correspond with $\exists x$. The outer $\forall x$ is interpreted as an unrelated variable, so it is the same as $\forall y\exists x(x<x)$.

Comment: Too confusing. Better might be: $~~\forall x\in R: \exists y\in R: x<y$

Comment: I don't see why you say it is "not deserving of a truth value".  To my mind it clearly deserves a value of false.  More of concern is the double binding of a single variable. $\forall x \exists x$ I'd translate as "For every $x$ there exists itself" which.... I guess is not really an issue.

Comment: @DanChristensen This is not the usual convention for evaluating sentences with repeated variables. $\forall x\exists x(x<x)$ is equivalent to $\exists x(x<x)$, not $\forall x\exists y(x<y)$, which means something completely different. But in any case, I agree with Peter Smith that it's better to set up the syntax to avoid such confusing sentences altogether.

Comment: @fleablood See my comment to Dan Christensen. Your suggestion makes it sound like $\forall x\exists x(x<x)$ should be equivalent to $\forall x (x<x)$, not to $\exists x(x<x)$.

Comment: Maybe you are right. In fact I know you are right. .... I think.  $\forall x(....)$= "For all $x$ something happens"= "Something happens that may or may not involve $x$".   $\forall x(\exists x(....))$= "For all $x$ something happens.. and what happens is there exists an $x$ where something else happens".  That the $x$ is tagged as the the same $x$ in the "for all $x$"... well, I could see this swinging both ways.  But I'll accept what they authorities say. Hierarchy of labeling has a certain consistency.

Comment: @Sam It is a basic and common courtesy in this site to accept and upvote answers. That is the only way you reward the user who has taken time to answer your question. You have not done so in many of your posts. I think you have been in this site long enough to know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it *problematic* to allow for expressions such as
$\forall x\exists x (x < x)$
to count as well formed sentences? No (as others have explained). You can set up your formal first-order logical languages that way, while keeping everything working systematically in an acceptable way.

Is is *necessary* to allow for expressions such as
$\forall x\exists x (x < x)$
to count as well formed sentences? Not at all. You can set up the construction rules for your first-order languages so that the things go along these lines: if $\varphi(n)$ is a sentence involving occurrences of the name/parameter $n$, but involving no occurrences of the variable $\xi$, then $\forall \xi\varphi(\xi)$ and $\exists \xi\varphi(\xi)$ are sentences. This sort of construction rule doesn't generate repeated or vacuous quantifiers.

Does it *matter* which way we go? Formally no. But perhaps conceptually, the second approach is to be preferred. The idea is that the key semantically-relevant unit is not a bare quantifier expression $\forall x$ but rather $\forall x \ldots x \ldots x \ldots$, the quantifier prefix plus its associated variables, which taken together make a composite expression which applied to an expression of type S/N (a perhaps complex predicate) yields an expression of type S.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is. The $\forall x$ isn’t quantifying any free variables, since there are no free variables in $\exists x \ x<x$, and the $\forall x$ is therefore called a ‘null quantifier’. However, using the standard semantics for quantifiers we can still evaluate such a statement: we effectively ask: is it true for all objects in our domain that $\exists x \ x<x$ is true? And note, if $\exists x \ x<x$ is true, then it is true that 'for all objects' $\exists x \ x<x$ is true.

Indeed, it turns out that $\forall x \ P$ is equivalent to just $P$ if $P$ does not contain any free variables. Same goes for a null existential quantifier. As such, we have the following  well recognized equivalence principles:

**Null Quantification**

where $P$ does not contain any free variables $x$, we have:

$\forall x \ P \Leftrightarrow P$

$\exists x \ P \Leftrightarrow P$

So no, there is no problem with allowing null quantifiers. And the fact that we have multiple quantifiers quantifying over the same variable isn't an issue either. Indeed, if it helps you to think about this, we can note that $\forall x \exists x \ x < x$ is equivalent to $\forall y  \exists x \ x < x$ : both have null quantifiers that can simply be removed.

In fact, sometimes when we do formal logical manipulations it is handy to allow these null quantifiers. Consider the following demonstration of one of the Prenex laws that says that if $P$ contains no free variables $x$ then $P \land \forall x Q \Leftrightarrow \forall x (P \land Q)$

Going from right to left:

$\forall x (P \land Q) \Leftrightarrow$

$\forall x \ P \land \forall x \ Q$ (by distribution of $\forall$ over $\land$) $\Leftrightarrow$

$P \land \forall x \ Q$ (by Null quantification)